# Choco-solver: coefficients of the variables are real numbers

Tags: choco, real-number

I am looking for a way to encode mathematical equations on Choco Solver. I see there's a way to encode constraints like:

```
3x + 4y < 9
```

But I am trying to encode something like

```
3.5*x + 4.3*y < 9.3
```

where `x` and `y` are int vars and coefficients are real number.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: What do you mean by `encode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need reals, you need to install Ibex solver (http://www.ibex-lib.org/) that is used as a library to handle reals in choco (see specific installation http://www.ibex-lib.org/doc/java-install.html)

Best,

Jean-Guillaume Fages
https://www.cosling.com/